# AngularJS http.get() accessing json breaks controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm new to `AngularJS` and have been trying to parse a `json` using the `$http` method. I made a test `$scope.test = "working"; variable`, which works fine. After putting in my `$http` method code it stops working and the `$http` method isn't working either. Here is my `json`:

```
{
   "programmes":[
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "id":"1"
         },
         "name":"Arrow",
         "imagepath":"..\/img\/arrow.jpg"
      },
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "id":"2"
         },
         "name":"Fargo",
         "imagepath":"..\/img\/fargo.jpg"
      },
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "id":"3"
         },
         "name":"You, me and the Apocalypse",
         "imagepath":"..\/img\/youme.jpg"
      },
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "id":"4"
         },
         "name":"Heat",
         "imagepath":"..\/img\/heat.jpg"
      },
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "id":"5"
         },
         "name":"The Thick of It",
         "imagepath":"..\/img\/thick.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

and here is my controller file:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "works";

    $http.get("../../jsons/programmes.json").success(function(response) {$scope.programmes = response.programmes;});

}]);
```

and finally, my html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in programmes">
    {{ x.name }}
  </li>
</ul>

<p>{{test}}</p>
```

so with the `$http.get()` in the controller, `{{test}}` shows up literally, but when I remove it, it shows 'works'. The `ng-repeat` `ul` doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to inject the $http angular service in your controller.
You can take a look at your browser console. Generally it gives you a hint on what you missed.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
```

You're seeing the angular expression `{{test}}` because your missing dependency breaks your controller code.